# CSS: Making nested min-height consistent

Tags: html, nested, css

For some reason, nested elements with `min-height` do not inherit the height of the grandparent in certain browsers.

```
<html style="height: 100%">
    <body style="min-height: 100%">
        <div style="min-height: 100%; background: #CCC">
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I haven't bothered testing much between different browser versions, but in Chrome 26 and Opera 12.14, it displays as I would expect, a gray background covering most of the screen with Hello World in the top left corner.

However, in IE 9 and Firefox 20, the gray background is only the height of a single line of text.
Testing further, adding:

**`position: relative`** to the div changes nothing
**`min-height: inherit`** on the div also changes nothing
**`position: absolute`** changes the width, but the `height` is 100% in all the above browsers except IE 9, where the background covers only the text.
**`position: fixed`** is similar to `position: absolute`, except IE 9 reverts to the original behaviour of 100% width.
**`float: left`** is similar to `position: absolute`, except Firefox 20 also shrinks the background to cover only the text.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property:

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'

Is `min-height` considered explicit or not?  I think that is the confusion between the browsers.  With `position: absolute`, it fixes Firefox, and only IE 9 has unexpected behaviour (which is not that unexpected, being IE).

Is it possible to get this consistent across the major browsers?

Please do not suggest answers that require JavaScript, or the body having a fixed height.  I know those are possible workarounds, but isn't what I'm trying to achieve.  Using `position: absolute` also breaks my layout as it pulls the element out of the flow, and for positioning below a dynamically sized element, the only workaround is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your observation:

> in Chrome 26 and Opera 12.14, it displays as I would expect, a gray background covering most of the screen with Hello World in the top left corner.

does seem to be incorrect, in my Chrome version 26 it only shows a gray background the height of a single line of text. (Just like Firefox and IE9). Which I believe is exactly right according to the w3 spec which you are quoting from, as the height of the `body` containing the `div` is not specified explicitly.

You can do something with `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell`. You won't need `min-height` at all then. I have tested this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KV23/2/) in **Chrome 26**, **Safari 5.1.7**, **Firefox 20**, **IE10**, **IE10 in IE9 mode**, **IE10 in IE8 mode** and it renders exactly the same in all of these browsers, it starts to break when using **IE10 in IE7 mode**.

**CSS**

```
html {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table-row;
}
div {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #CCC;
}
```